# Stack that you can move nth element to the top of the stack

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I'm looking for a Stack data structure that also allows moving the nth element to the top of the stack. So in addition to pop(), push(), peek() I want something like moveToTop(int n) where the top of the stack n=0 and the bottom of the stack n=size-1.

What would be the best way to implement that? I'm working in Java.

Comment: You can implement your own stack.

Answer (score 2):

there is no the moveToTop methed in standard stack data structure ,but if you want to do,i think you can implement like follows:

```
public class MyStack<T> extends Stack<T>{

    public synchronized void moveToTop(int n) throws Exception {
        int size = this.size();
        if(n>size) {
            throw new Exception("error position");
        }
        T ele = remove(n);
        push(ele);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a remove() method that takes an index as parameter in Stack implementation.

Comment: lol,here i just reuse the stack from java libary,stack.remove inherit from verctor.remove , if you use other language,you can implements more deails,eg: remove,push or if c++,use STL

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent? Simple is Stack class
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html
It inherits remove(int index) from Vector.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another array or other underlying structure to hold items temporarily. Move the items in front of item n into that, push that items back and push the item you want to top of that.

```
public class MyStack<T> {
    T items[size];
    ....
    void moveToTop(int n)
    {
        T obj = items[n];
        T[] tempItems = new T[n - 1];
        Arrays.copyOf(items, n - 1);
        System.arraycopy(items, 0, tempItems, 0, n - 1);
        System.arraycopy(tempItems, 0, items, 1, n - 1);
        items[0] = obj;
    }
    ....
}
```

Removed other parts for brevity.
Instead of doing all this hassle, you can check Double-Linked list or Skip List.

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.LinkedList` fulfills your requirement, because it's `linked list` / `stack` / `queue` at the same time.

Relevant methods:

- `public E remove(int index)`
  Remove by index, and get the removed value.
- `public void push(E e)`
  Push to top.

So, what you need to do is:

- Figure out the index.
- Remove it by index, and get the return value.
- Push the return value to top.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple ways to implement stack that I know:

**- Implement it using extension of Vector**

**- Implement it using any List component**

**- Implement it as a Linked Data Structure**

**- Implement it using underlying Java Array**

I suggest you to implement it with using underlying Java Array. It's hard to implement comparing to others but it will be really helpful to understand the logic.